# Pass blocks into an included template without extending

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to know the best way to include a template many times throughout a project and possibly many times within a parent template. This included child template is just a skeleton that must be filled with both variables and blocks of html. Example templates:

parent.html:

```
<p>Popup #1</p>
{% include "popup.html" %}
<p>Popup #2</p>
{% include "popup.html" %}
```

popup.html:

```
<h1 class="title">{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
<div class="body">{% block body %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

The only solution i can think of is to have a separate file for every popup and extend popup.html in each file. Then, I could include these extended files into my parent. This requires adding a file for every popup which would be frustrating.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The Django template engine falls down in this area. There's no way to include files *and* parse blocks in them. You can pass data into the include, allowing you do something like:

```
<h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
<div class="body">{{ body }}</div>
```

But if you need actual blocks, they have to be directly in the main template file, or one of its parents.

Comment: Alright, I was afraid to hear that. D: I'll probably stick with the one solution I discussed in my post. It adds some complexity but it does do what I need.